# android beginner tutorial Error parsing XML

Tags: android

I have just started the beginner's tutorial on android and I get 4 errors when compiling, even tho the code is basically copied from the webpage and I have followed all the steps. The errors are as follows:

- Element type "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". activity_main.xml   /test/res/layout    line 6  Android XML Format Problem
- R cannot be resolved to a variable    MainActivity.java   /test/src/com/example/test  line 12 Java Problem
- R cannot be resolved to a variable    MainActivity.java   /test/src/com/example/test  line 19 Java Problem
- error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) activity_main.xml   /test/res/layout    line 6  Android AAPT Problem]

Here is the code:
activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" /> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.test;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

I searched everywhere, tried everything and it still won't work, so this is my last hope. Thanks!

Comment: A good habit to develop is use of white space.  See how I've edited your example and how it makes the mistake much easier to see?

Comment: I actually used white space originally, but I was afraid maybe using it was the cause of the error. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Copy this, clean project and run. You didn't ended the LinearLayout tag before EditText.

Answer (score 2):

Your LinearLayout tag should be closed.

i.e

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" <-- close here
```

like this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Comment: Thank you very much, totally slipped my attention